# Headless CentOS 7 in VirtualBox: edit / verify /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0sN scripts

Tags: networking, virtualbox, networkmanager

I have a non-gui CentOS 7 linux running in a VirtualBox on my (Windows) desktop computer. Recently, we had some trouble with our networking setup, making the DHCP-based networking fail; for a few days, I had trouble with my Linux box as well. During my struggle, I messed up the configuration of that box a little (experimenting with VirtualBox network adapters etc.).

Now, the "normal" networking works again, but in my vbox, I suddenly had trouble again; the time (which used to simply work) was behind the Windows machine by 6 days. And the route to important external resources was broken - I couldn't reach Github anymore, for example.

Obviously, the networking is managed by NetworkManager:

```
# LANG=C nmcli general
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN
connected  full          enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
# LANG=C nmcli device
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
enp0s8  ethernet  connected  Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1
```

The `ifconfig` command told me that in fact the `enp0s8` was used; but the information didn't match. For example, according to `ifconfig enp0s8`, the IP4 address (`inet`) was `192.168.33.199`, while the `IPADDR` values in the `ifcfg-*` files were different outdated values.

In my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` directory, I had some garbage; among the `ifcfg-*` files I had an `ifcfg-Kabelgebundene_Verbindung_1` file (with `NAME="Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1"`, so this was the refered script); but  the IP address etc. were outdated, and the matching `route-Kabelgebundene_Verbindung_1` was empty. I had non-empty `route-*` files, though.

So my idea was to manually fix those files, using information from the `ifconfig enp0s8` output.

First of all, I don't fully understand the information in the `ifcfg-*` files. There are `HWADDR` values, and there are (sometimes, different) `MACADDR` values. In an (outdated) `ifcfg-enp0s3` file, I have both `HWADDR` and `MACADDR`, and the `MACADDR` here is the same as the `HWADDR` in `ifcfg-Kabelgebundene_Verbindung_1` (which in turn doesn't contain a `MACADDR` value).

I expect the hardware address from `ifconfig` ("`ether`") to be correct under all circumstances, right?

So, my plan was:

- Choose one set of scripts (in my case, `{ifcfg,route}-Kabelgebundene_Verbindung_1`), and throw away the others (preserving `*-lo`, of course).
- In the `ifcfg-*` file,

  - set `HWADDR` to the `ether` value from `ifconfig`
  - set `IPADDR` to the `inet` value from `ifconfig`

It turned out that I was able to use `BOOTPROTO=dhcp` instead of setting `IPADDR` (and others) manually, since the DHCP server (in the other subnet, sigh ...) was found using the information in the corresponding `route-*` script.

I was not sure whether the adjusted scripts would have been used when doing something like `ifconfig down enp0s8; ifconfig up enp0s8`; so, after verifying my root password (to be sure I'd be able to login directly to the box, without ssh/PuTTY), I simply rebooted, and it worked.

What I couldn't work out yet:

- What are these `UUID` values? I had different values, probably from different virtual network adapters, and I couldn't find them in the `VBoxManage showvminfo "<vm name>"` output. It was a matter of an "educated guess".
- What would have been the best method to test my changes?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method to setup/restore networking on a headless server may be to use the "nmtui" interactive text-based menu.

```
$ yum install NetworkManager-tui
$ nmtui
```

```
                      ┌───────────────────────────┐
                      │                           │ 
                      │ ┌─────────────┐           │ 
                      │ │ Ethernet  ↑ │ <Add>     │ 
                      │ │   enp4s0  ▒ │           │ 
                      │ │ Bridge    ▒ │ <Edit...> │ 
                      │ │   virbr0  ▮ │           │ 
                      │ │   cni0    ▒ │ <Delete>  │ 
                      │ │   br0     ▒ │           │ 
                      │ │           ▒ │           │ 
                      │ │           ▒ │           │ 
                      │ │           ▒ │           │ 
                      │ │           ▒ │           │ 
                      │ │           ↓ │ <Back>    │ 
                      │ └─────────────┘           │ 
                      │                           │ 
                      └───────────────────────────┘
```